# mining revenue equation difference to calculators

Tags: mining-profitability

I am interested in the revenue calculation of mining process.
From a few references like [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/explain-the-math-behind-mining-profitability-calculators) I found a equation that people say it's correct.

Unfortunatelly it differs to the results which are calculated by public available calculators like [this](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/btc).

with a hashing power of **13.5 TH/s** the referenced calculator and others resulting in **0.001304 BTC per day**. The equation in the other thread results in **0.002134 BTC per day**.

```
H = 13500 GH/s * 10^9 = 13,500,000,000,000
B = 12.5
D = 1,590,896,927,258

(86400 * 13,500,000,000,000 * 12.5) / (2^32 * 1,590,896,927,258) =
  0.002134 BTC/d
```

Could anybody please help me to understand whats the right way to calculate an approx. revenue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your equation matches my understanding of what is correct.  At the bottom of the Cryptocompare page is a note that "Mining metrics are calculated based on a network hash rate of 18,633,837,452 GH/s".  Multiplying by 600 and dividing by 2^32, this would correspond to a difficulty of 2.6e12 rather than your 1.6e12 which is in fact the current figure.  Perhaps this represents some estimate of future difficulty?

Comment: yes. looks like thats the point. thank you very much. that means I have to calculate the network hash rate all the time to use the same equation.